# Check for status updates using APEX.SERVER.PROCESS

Tags: javascript, ajax, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

*Env: Oracle APEX v5.1.2 with Oracle 12c R2 DB*

I have a report that is based off the following table columns in a table called `MY_TASK`:

```
TASK_ID (PK),
TASK,
TASK_STATUS (from TASK_CHECKER.task_status)
```

I also have another table that I use as a running table to check the status of a job that relates to the TASK_ID number from table MY_TASK called `TASK_CHECKER` which has the columns:

```
TASK_ID (PK),
TASK_STATUS
```

Based on the above, I have a scheduled job that regularly checks the status of another table for a specific TASK_ID, which updates the TASK_STATUS value within the TASK_CHECKER table.

Using the above, when the user runs the Oracle APEX app and goes to the MY_TASK report page, I would like through the use of **apex.server.process**, at startup, join the two tables together via TASK_ID and display the TASK_STATUS at the time within the MY_TASK report.

Please note that the TASK_STATUS values are: **WAITING** / **IN-PROGRESS** / **SUCCESS** or **FAILED**

So if I had 5 TASK_IDs running, I might see at page load:

```
1    TASK_A   SUCCESS
2    TASK_B   ERROR
3    TASK_C   IN-PROGRESS
4    TASK_D   WAITING
5    TASK_E   WAITING
```

and perhaps 10 seconds later change to:

```
1    TASK_A   SUCCESS
2    TASK_B   ERROR
3    TASK_C   SUCCESS
4    TASK_D   SUCCESS
5    TASK_E   IN-PROGRESS
```

Would like to see TASK_STATUS updates appear in real time.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to just refresh the region every N seconds. Would that work?

Comment: @DanMcGhan - Hi Dan, that would work but just wondering whether I could use apex.server.process and refreshing an Interactive Grid does seem to work using apex.region("region_static_id").refresh() . I'm just after a means of refreshing the IG every N seconds without locking the screen, while the user is on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and it seems that `refresh` is async (it doesn't lock the screen). You should be able to do something like this...

```
setInterval(function() {
  apex.region("region_static_id").refresh();
}, 5000);
```

Just make sure the number of milliseconds is higher than the amount of time the region takes the query to run and the region to render.

Comment: Does this also work for Interactive Grids and I thought this is done differently for IG's?